# I need a library name

Tags: c

I am new at Ubuntu and I'm studying about FILEs to learn in C programming. I wrote my codes, however I can't run them cause of it wants me another library. So, Which library contains the FILEs? I was using just `#include <stdio.h>` but in ubuntu it's a bit different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    FILE *ptrFILE;
    if(ptrFILE = fopen("Test.txt","w")==NULL)
    {
        printf("The  file couldn't opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=20; i++)
    {
            fprintf(fptrFILE,"%d\n", i*5);
    }
    fclose(ptrFILE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you include <stdio.h> ?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you install it correctly?

Comment: Does your code compile successfully, but fail to link?

Comment: Please **improve your question** (so **edit it**) by showing your compilation command and some of your source code.

Comment: It's edited, I'm using ubuntu/ eclipse / c

Comment: What does “cause of it wants me another library” mean? Is the compiler showing an error message? [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30945527/edit) your question to include the message.

Comment: When `fopen`  fails, you'll better call `perror`

Answer (score 2):

The `FILE`  data is an *opaque* `struct`  defined thru `<stdio.h>` and the implementation is in the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (it is *implicitly* linked by `gcc` - or `clang` - on Ubuntu).

So just compile your source file `aprog.c`  by running in your terminal

```
gcc -Wall -g aprog.c -o abinary
```

then run `./abinary` in the same terminal

<sup>Note that `-Wall` asks the `gcc` compiler for almost all warnings (add `-Wextra` to get even more) and `-g` asks for debug information (to be able to use the `gdb`  debugger, or [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), later).</sup>

Don't forget to install the `build-essential` and the `libc6-dev` Ubuntu packages